# I want to chose an item randomly from a list but there is an error

Tags: list, random, python-3.7

I wanted to make a password generator but there is an error
This is the part needed to recreate the error.

```
from random import *
Adj = ['Boring', 'Fun', 'Sleepy', 'Ultimate', 'Small', 'Big', 'Dumb']
Adjectives2 = random.choice(Adj)
```

It showed an AttributeError.

```
AttributeError:'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

I tried asking other's and they said the same thing.
Use the 'random.choice()' function. They all were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `import` statement appears to be the problem.  Try using `import random` instead:

```
import random

Adj = ['Boring', 'Fun', 'Sleepy', 'Ultimate', 'Small', 'Big', 'Dumb']
Adjectives2 = random.choice(Adj)
print(Adjectives2)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can also keep the `from random import *` and use `choice(foo)`.

Comment: @ggorlen Weird that Python behaves this way.  In Java, using the fully qualified package name is always allowed, regardless of any imports.